# Present Perfect with Past Simple or Past Perfect

Tags: tense

Which tense suits here?

A: Have you ever used the things I **lent** you?

or

B: Have you ever used the things I **had lent** you?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use past perfect **had lent** to talk about something that happened before some other event that is usually specified in the same sentence.

> I finished my dinner when he arrived.

In this sentence (simple past), the finishing took place around the time that he arrived.

> I had finished my dinner when he arrived.

In this sentence (past perfect), the finishing took place before the time that he arrived.

In your sentence, there is no other event for the lending to be before, so you cannot use past perfect: simple past is fine.